# exact reference of some Pushkin's verses

Tags: перевод

I was asked about one (or two ?) Russian verse(s) by a colleague of mine asking if I could find their exact reference. He had in memory a rough translation (in French) and remembered only that Pushkin was their author :

> The hurricane has passed away / very few survived /

The French translation my colleague gave me :

> L'ouragan a passé / bien peu ont survécu /

I can't find these words in the few Pushkin's poems I already know; Google didn't return any relevant results.

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're after, but there's a poem by Sergei Yesenin, written in 1924, [Русь Советская (Soviet Russia)](http://feb-web.ru/feb/esenin/texts/es2/es2-094-.htm), which starts with this text:

> **Тот ураган прошел. Нас мало уцелело.**
>   На перекличке дружбы многих нет.
>   Я вновь вернулся в край осиротелый,
>   В котором не был восемь лет.

The first line can be translated into English, roughly, as

> That hurricane has passed.  Very few of us survived.

I haven't been able to find any reference to a similar text by Pushkin.

Comment: This answer seems perfect to me : thank you very much.